# Android bring App back to foreground

Tags: android, android-intent

I am devloping an app that has to work in the background and come back up when I get an event from some server.

For that I have a Service that runs in the background and gets messages. What I tought I could do was just start the Activity. Like this:

```
Intent ROA = new Intent(MainActivity.getInstance(), RouteOverviewActivity.class);
MainActivity.getInstance().startActivity(ROA);
```

The problem is this. The code gets executed but the app is not pushed in the foreground. When I reopen the app by hand, it opens at the activity I started in the background.

So everything works exept that the app is pushed to the foreground.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Bear in mind that the user may not like you interrupting them in the middle of whatever they are doing, by forcing your activity back to the foreground.

Comment: I know. My app is devloped for people that have to work with this app, its there job to answer the app. This is not an app for normal people.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use your service as the context to start the activity, i.e from inside your service code:

```
Intent ROA = new Intent(this, RouteOverviewActivity.class);
startActivity(ROA);
```